# MVC Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I wanted to use bootstrap's carousel for my Library project. I wanted to display 3 books in a row each time. Currently my code which does work involves only 1 book:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @{
            var first = true;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="carousel-item @(first ? Html.Raw("active") : Html.Raw(""))">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm"><img class="d-block w-100" src="~/Content/BookImages/@item.Image" alt="@item.Title"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            first = false;
        }
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
       data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
       data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out so I could display 3 books in each row?
Also is there a way to implement for loop instead of for each loop? I am asking because I would like to do another carousel for new books in library and i would like it to display 6 last books (3 in a row) added to library.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to change the slider to something like this:
[Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

If you still want to use bootstrap carousel then you will have to clone items in your list of items and then add active class to 3 items via javascript and on each translate move the active classes via JS to 3 items to display.

With slick slider, you just have to add something like this and will do the trick:

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
 infinite: true,
 slidesToShow: 3,
 slidesToScroll: 3
});
```